# Black Body Radiation and Tungsten Filament?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

I’m trying to understand Black Body Radiation and a specific case of tungsten filament light bulb. I read that these filaments have a color temperature of 4,400 degrees F yet a thermal image of a light bulb shows a bulb temperature of around 350 degrees F. These numbers conflict.

Can anyone explain why they are different and point me in the right direction for understanding color temperature vs physical bulb temperature?

Comment: For those wondering that is about 2426  degrees C and  176 degrees C.

Comment: Did you do the experiment yourself? Are you observing the thermal light from the filament directly or through the lightbulb?

Comment: They do have different temperatures. There is no conflict. The hot bulb may give you a bad burn but is nowhere close to 2000 degrees C. The filament is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

light bulbs are usually designed so that the bulb temperature is below the ignition point for paper, which is about 450 F. The intensity of the filament output drops with distance from the filament and so when the filament heats the bulb, that output is diluted across the area of the bulb and achieves an equilibrium temperature below 450 F- which, for a frosted bulb, is what you are measuring. This furnishes the "standard size" of a typical 60 watt light bulb.

Miniature quartz-halogen light bulbs have the bulb wall so close to the filament inside that the bulb temperature will be high enough to ignite paper and cloth, making them a fire hazard. Note that the bulb also has to be made from quartz because ordinary glass would soften at those temperatures.

Comment: So the filament is 4,400 deg F, but the bulb is closer to 450 deg F?

Comment: yup, that's right. distance does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the camera is not able to resolve the filament. If a pixel in the detector (at the image) corresponds to a larger width than the filament (at the object), the camera will estimate a radiant intensity which is lower than that actually emitted by the filament.

This assumes that the camera's temperature estimate is based on intensity (via the Stefan-Boltzmann law). If the camera estimate is based on colour (e.g. via Wien's displacement law), it's possible that this was modified by different absorption by different wavelengths in the glass bulb.